# Evaluate the following integral: $\int\frac{\left(2-x^2\right)\mathrm{e}^x}{\left(1-x\right)^\frac{3}{2}} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the following integral (from the 2006 MIT Integration Bee):
$$\int\dfrac{\left(2-x^2\right)\mathrm{e}^x}{\left(1-x\right)^\frac{3}{2}} \, dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{2 - x^2}{(1 - x)^{3/2}}\,e^x\,\text{d}x
& = 
\int \frac{1}{(1 - x)^{3/2}}\,e^x\,\text{d}x 
+
\int \frac{1 - x^2}{(1 - x)^{3/2}}\,e^x\,\text{d}x \\
& = 
\frac{2\,e^x}{\sqrt{1 - x}} 
- 
\int \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 - x}}\,e^x\,\text{d}x
+
\int \frac{1 + x}{\sqrt{1 - x}}\,e^x\,\text{d}x \\
& = 
\frac{2\,e^x}{\sqrt{1 - x}} 
- 
\int \frac{1 - x}{\sqrt{1 - x}}\,e^x\,\text{d}x \\
& = 
\frac{2\,e^x}{\sqrt{1 - x}} 
- 
\int e^x\,\sqrt{1 - x}\,\text{d}x \\
& = 
\frac{2\,e^x}{\sqrt{1 - x}} 
- 
e^x\,\sqrt{1 - x}
-
\int \frac{1}{2\,\sqrt{1 - x}}\,e^x\,\text{d}x \\
& = 
\frac{1 + x}{\sqrt{1 - x}}\,e^x
-
e\int \frac{1}{2\,\sqrt{1 - x}}\,e^{x-1}\,\text{d}x \\
& = 
\frac{1 + x}{\sqrt{1 - x}}\,e^x
-
e\int \frac{1}{2\,t}\,e^{-t^2}\left(-2\,t\,\text{d}t\right) \\
& = 
\frac{1 + x}{\sqrt{1 - x}}\,e^x
+
\frac{e\,\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\int \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\,e^{-t^2}\,\text{d}t \\
& = 
\frac{1 + x}{\sqrt{1 - x}}\,e^x
+
\frac{e\,\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\,\text{erf}(t) + c \\
& = 
\frac{1 + x}{\sqrt{1 - x}}\,e^x
+
\frac{e\,\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\,\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{1 - x}\,\right) + c \,.
\end{aligned}
$$